# JNI call to OpenSSL causes SIGSEGV

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm pretty new to android NDK development and have problem with this small encryption function (uses OpenSSL underneath):

```
jint
Java_org_openssl_LibCrypto_PKCS5PBKDF2HMACSHA1(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring password, jbyteArray salt, jint iterationCount, jbyteArray key) {

    jint ret;
    const char *passwordCStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, password, 0);
    jsize keyjLen     = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, key);
    jbyte *keyjBytes  = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, key, 0);
    jsize saltjLen     = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, salt);
    jbyte *saltjBytes  = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, salt, 0);

    ret = PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(passwordCStr, strlen(passwordCStr),
            saltjBytes, saltjLen, iterationCount,
            keyjLen, keyjBytes);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, password, passwordCStr);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, key,    keyjBytes,    0);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, salt,   saltjBytes,   0);
}
```

the problem is that it causes SIGSEGV, but only on some devices (like Nexus 7 - crashes on both android 4.4 and 4.3, but works ok on Nexus 5). I've tried upgrading the OpenSSL library, so currently I'm using the latest one (1.0.1i with fips 2.0.8), but didn't help. here's the long crash log:

```
09-17 12:41:52.012: A/libc(17238): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 17295 (Thread-453)
09-17 12:41:52.072: I/DEBUG(177): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-17 12:41:52.072: I/DEBUG(177): Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
09-17 12:41:52.072: I/DEBUG(177): Revision: '0'
09-17 12:41:52.072: I/DEBUG(177): pid: 17238, tid: 17295, name: Thread-453  >>> com.testing.encryption <<<
09-17 12:41:52.072: I/DEBUG(177): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 76b0ff48  r3 00000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     r4 00000000  r5 76b105a8  r6 00000008  r7 41f1d2f8
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     r8 78242b10  r9 760f3e7c  sl 76b0ff58  fp 78242b24
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     ip 756ecfe4  sp 78242ad0  lr 756ea01b  pc 4013dfd8  cpsr 400e0030
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d4  62617461642f6572  d5  6572632f73657361
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d6  736c6169746e6564  d7  6c616e72756f6a2d
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d16 000000000000120c  d17 0000000000001208
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d18 0000000000000004  d19 5c5c5c5c5c5c5c5c
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d20 c02e000000000000  d21 c024000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 c02e000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d24 0001000200020001  d25 0006000500040003
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 4024000000000000
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     scr 80000012
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177): backtrace:
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #00  pc 00022fd8  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+83)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #01  pc 00002017  /data/app-lib/com.testing.encryption-1/libcrypto-jni.so (Java_org_openssl_LibCrypto_PKCS5PBKDF2HMACSHA1+88)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #02  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #03  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #04  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #05  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #06  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #07  pc 00060581  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #08  pc 000605a5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #09  pc 0005528b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #10  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #11  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177): stack:
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242a90  41f1d2e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242a94  415924b1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242a98  41f1d2e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242a9c  76b0ff48  [anon:libc_malloc]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242aa0  415f8564  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242aa4  78242abc  [stack:17295]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242aa8  41f1d2e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242aac  4159252d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ab0  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ab4  4159434f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ab8  76b105a8  [anon:libc_malloc]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242abc  76b0ff48  [anon:libc_malloc]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ac0  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ac4  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ac8  76b105a8  [anon:libc_malloc]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242acc  756ea013  /data/app-lib/com.testing.encryption-1/libcrypto-jni.so (Java_org_openssl_LibCrypto_PKCS5PBKDF2HMACSHA1+84)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #00  78242ad0  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          ........  ........
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #01  78242ad0  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ad4  fffffea0  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ad8  41576f54  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*))
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242adc  4157463c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+188)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ae0  59d00005  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ae4  41f1d368  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242ae8  00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242aec  00000010  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242af0  760f3e9c  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242af4  6d819aa8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242af8  76b0ff48  [anon:libc_malloc]
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242afc  00000004  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b00  760f3e8c  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b04  41566bd0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):     #02  78242b08  0000000a  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b0c  44700009  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b10  760f3e78  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b14  00000001  
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b18  751586e3  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.testing.encryption-1.apk@classes.dex
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b1c  41f119c8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b20  422a0220  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
09-17 12:41:52.192: I/DEBUG(177):          78242b24  41597127  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+402)
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near r2:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff28 00000000 00000000 00000008 40289a24  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff38 760ece20 76b2b74c 00000000 0000045b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff48 6e56d80c 760f3e78 6d829a70 753d0000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff58 00000000 00000000 78242c40 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff68 78242c94 0000000c 00000000 41566d40  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff78 00000000 00000000 6c87d070 760f0300  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff88 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff98 00000000 76b2aef8 41566d40 4156bc00  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffa8 00000000 4156fcfc 4156fd70 4156fc20  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffb8 4156fc40 4156fc9c 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffc8 757379a8 00000028 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffd8 00000000 00000000 00001ffc 415f891c  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffe8 415ff0e0 6d4bc110 00000003 76b103a0  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0fff8 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10008 00000003 6eaba158 6eaba158 00000005  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10018 6eab515c 6d7f94a8 3d6e32cb 66083608  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near r5:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10588 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10598 d1d1d1d1 d1d1d1d1 00000000 0000002b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105a8 415f14b8 00000000 0000000c 76b0ff48  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105b8 00000000 00000000 7572f5c0 0056293b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105c8 00000028 000002f3 e8028230 010203a0  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105d8 00010202 09060d30 8648862a 01010df7  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105e8 30000505 300b3163 55030609 02130604  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b105f8 21315355 03061f30 130a0455 65685418  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10608 206f4720 64646144 72472079 2c70756f  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10618 636e4920 3031312e 5503062f 28130b04  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10628 44206f47 79646461 616c4320 32207373  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10638 72654320 69666974 69746163 41206e6f  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10648 6f687475 79746972 0d171e30 36303430  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10658 37313932 30323630 330d175a 32363034  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10668 30373139 5a303236 0b316330 03060930  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10678 13060455 31535502 061f3021 0a045503  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near r7:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d2d8 00000000 0000000a 00610065 00000023  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d2e8 415ff800 00000000 00000008 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d2f8 64cf580a 3f820d53 0079006d 0000002b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d308 415ff800 00000000 00000010 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d318 fccbd45d 3b45f596 fccbd45d 3b45f596  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d328 006d0078 0000002b 41f124e0 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d338 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d348 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000002b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d358 415ff800 00000000 00000010 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d368 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d378 4161aef8 00000049 41ed5ad0 00000001  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d388 00000067 0000003b 415ff950 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d398 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d3a8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d3b8 00000000 00000000 00000048 00000022  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     41f1d3c8 415ff0e0 00000000 41ed5ad0 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near r8:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242af0 760f3e9c 6d819aa8 76b0ff48 00000004  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b00 760f3e8c 41566bd0 0000000a 44700009  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b10 760f3e78 00000001 751586e3 41f119c8  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b20 422a0220 41597127 760f3e78 751586de  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b30 756e9fbf 76b0ff58 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b40 00000000 00000000 00000000 40169384  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b50 78242bd4 00000000 415e75bd 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b60 00000000 78242b48 00000000 00000002  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b70 00000034 75189861 76b102b4 4159a9a3  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b80 415f3c74 41f118d0 00000000 00000020  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b90 00000020 41ec8008 00000001 00000020  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ba0 415f81f0 754217ec 422a0220 41f1d358  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bb0 ffffffff 41f1d358 00000000 00000008  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bc0 00000008 41ec8008 00000001 00000008  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bd0 415f81f0 754000b8 422a0220 41f119c8  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     78242be0 ffffffff 41f119c8 41548320 415bc19d  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near r9:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3e5c 760f3eac 6eda9974 760f3ea0 74fc577e  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3e6c 6d819aa8 00000000 00000000 7d900001  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3e7c 00000000 59d00005 0000000a 44700009  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3e8c 760f3ed0 74f15e36 6d829a70 74fc577e  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3e9c 00000000 6d63f460 41f119c8 41f1d2e8  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3eac 0000000a 41f1d358 41f1d2c0 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3ebc 760f3f14 74f1328e 6d819e30 74f15e36  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3ecc 00000000 41f1d2c0 74f15f28 41eed8f8  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3edc 00000000 00000000 41f11990 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3eec 00000000 0000001e 41f20c38 422df278  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3efc 4227ff28 760f3f50 74f14dba 6d8188f8  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3f0c 74f1328e 00000000 422eb620 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3f1c 422df278 41eef720 41f20c38 41f0de90  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3f2c 41f1fe30 00000000 422920d8 4227ff28  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3f3c 760f3f80 74f0cab0 6d819508 74f14dba  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     760f3f4c 00000000 00000001 422ecd10 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177): memory near sl:
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff38 760ece20 76b2b74c 00000000 0000045b  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff48 6e56d80c 760f3e78 6d829a70 753d0000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff58 00000000 00000000 78242c40 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff68 78242c94 0000000c 00000000 41566d40  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff78 00000000 00000000 6c87d070 760f0300  
09-17 12:41:52.202: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff88 00000000 00000000 00000001 00004000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ff98 00000000 76b2aef8 41566d40 4156bc00  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffa8 00000000 4156fcfc 4156fd70 4156fc20  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffb8 4156fc40 4156fc9c 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffc8 757379a8 00000028 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffd8 00000000 00000000 00001ffc 415f891c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0ffe8 415ff0e0 6d4bc110 00000003 76b103a0  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b0fff8 00000001 00000040 00000200 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10008 00000003 6eaba158 6eaba158 00000005  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10018 6eab515c 6d7f94a8 3d6e32cb 66083608  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     76b10028 a36248d8 5c5413f2 5924f6ef f45e5983  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177): memory near fp:
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b04 41566bd0 0000000a 44700009 760f3e78  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b14 00000001 751586e3 41f119c8 422a0220  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b24 41597127 760f3e78 751586de 756e9fbf  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b34 76b0ff58 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b44 00000000 00000000 40169384 78242bd4  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b54 00000000 415e75bd 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b64 78242b48 00000000 00000002 00000034  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b74 75189861 76b102b4 4159a9a3 415f3c74  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b84 41f118d0 00000000 00000020 00000020  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b94 41ec8008 00000001 00000020 415f81f0  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ba4 754217ec 422a0220 41f1d358 ffffffff  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bb4 41f1d358 00000000 00000008 00000008  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bc4 41ec8008 00000001 00000008 415f81f0  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bd4 754000b8 422a0220 41f119c8 ffffffff  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242be4 41f119c8 41548320 415bc19d 415f3c74  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242bf4 41ef2208 760f3ea0 00000008 41f119c8  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177): memory near ip:
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ecfc4 75639798 75638b10 75638ccc 40128c01  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ecfd4 756392a8 75639774 75638e88 75639014  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ecfe4 4013df85 75641480 756411c4 4012a091  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ecff4 4013c840 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed014 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed024 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed034 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed044 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed054 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed074 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed084 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed094 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed0a4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ed0b4 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177): memory near sp:
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ab0 00000000 4159434f 76b105a8 76b0ff48  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ac0 00000000 00000000 76b105a8 756ea013  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ad0 00000000 fffffea0 41576f54 4157463c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ae0 59d00005 41f1d368 00000000 00000010  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242af0 760f3e9c 6d819aa8 76b0ff48 00000004  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b00 760f3e8c 41566bd0 0000000a 44700009  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b10 760f3e78 00000001 751586e3 41f119c8  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b20 422a0220 41597127 760f3e78 751586de  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b30 756e9fbf 76b0ff58 00000000 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b40 00000000 00000000 00000000 40169384  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b50 78242bd4 00000000 415e75bd 00000000  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b60 00000000 78242b48 00000000 00000002  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b70 00000034 75189861 76b102b4 4159a9a3  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b80 415f3c74 41f118d0 00000000 00000020  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242b90 00000020 41ec8008 00000001 00000020  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     78242ba0 415f81f0 754217ec 422a0220 41f1d358  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177): code around pc:
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013dfb8 b31a2b01 0f04f013 800af000 3b04f851  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013dfc8 3c01f1a3 0c03ea2c 3c80f01c 8033f040  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013dfd8 2302e8f1 f040f891 3c01f1a2 0c02ea2c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013dfe8 3c80f01c 800ff040 3c01f1a3 0c03ea2c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013dff8 3c80f01c 801ff040 bfeaf7ff 0000eba1  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e008 0001f1a0 eba14770 ea5f0000 f040434c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e018 f0808009 ea5f800a f0400c4c f1a08009  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e028 47700005 0008f1a0 f1a04770 47700007  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e038 0006f1a0 eba14770 ea5f0000 f040434c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e048 f0808009 ea5f800a f0400c4c f1a08009  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e058 47700001 0004f1a0 f1a04770 47700003  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e068 0002f1a0 bf004770 1e0cb510 4807da02  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e078 e0034478 d904429c 44784805 f7ef2100  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e088 e8bdfcc5 f7f14010 bf00bb91 0001f03c  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e098 0001f050 b508429a 4805d904 44784903  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     4013e0a8 fcb4f7ef 4008e8bd ba52f01a 000138ee  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177): code around lr:
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756e9ff8 9005682b 599b9904 47981c28 9904682b  
09-17 12:41:52.212: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea008 59db1c06 22001c28 1c074798 f7ff1c20  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea018 9b0eeaf0 1c011c3a 9b079300 93011c20  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea028 93029b05 f7ff1c33 682aeaea 009b23aa  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea038 58d31c28 1c229906 682b4798 00b626c0  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea048 1c28599c 9a05990f 47a02300 1c28682b  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea058 599c9904 23001c3a b00947a0 b5f0bdf0  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea068 9207b08b 93056802 009b23a9 990758d3  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea078 1c052200 682b4798 00b626ab 599b1c04  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea088 99111c28 682b4798 00bf27b8 59db9008  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea098 99111c28 47982200 9006682b 599b9905  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea0a8 47981c28 9905682b 59db2200 1c289009  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea0b8 1c074798 f7ff1c20 1c06ea9c ea32f7ff  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea0c8 1c3a9b10 93009001 1c319b08 93021c20  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea0d8 26c09b06 930300b6 f7ff9b09 682aea96  
09-17 12:41:52.222: I/DEBUG(177):     756ea0e8 009b23aa 58d31c28 1c229907 682b4798  
09-17 12:41:52.372: I/BootReceiver(595): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
09-17 12:41:52.382: I/ActivityManager(595): Process com.testing.encryption (pid 17238) has died.
```

it would be great if somebody could give me may be just a hint. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like `libcrypto-jni.so` just OpenSSL's `libcrypto.so` but with a new name. Is this correct?

Comment: not really, the `libcrypto-jni.so` contains my functions (like the one mentioned) and `libcrypto.so` is the original OpenSSL library (compiled for android).

Comment: So you have a wrapper shared object, and you link to the static version of the OpenSL library (`libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a`). Is that correct?

Comment: yes, wrapper shared library (`libcrypto-jni.so`) and OpenSSL shared libraries (`libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`). from java I'm loading both and then using the functions for my wrapper shared library. anyways, I've found out what was causing this in the mean time. Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

so the cause of the crash was null pointer passed to the JNI function (`fault addr 00000000` tells us this) in `strlen` function, and weird thing is that on some devices this:

```
String a = null;
String b = a + "something";
```

results in `b` being set to `null`, but for some `b` is set to "nullsomething"...

Comment: *"... OpenSSL shared libraries (`libcrypto.so` and `libssl.so`)"* - this will cause you problems in the future. Android usually carries around version 0.9.8. You linked against version 1.0.1. They are ***not*** binary compatible. Your wrapper shared object needs to link against the static versions of the library. The reason its a problem is Zypote loads 0.9.8 at boot. When your app runs, symbols are resolved against the all-ready-loaded 0.9.8, and not your version of 1.0.1.

Comment: @jww interesting, thanks for sharing. so I'll rather really switch to using static libraries.